# Find the maximum , minimum, maximal, minimal element of this hasse diagram

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, relations

[image]

The hasse diagram can be made in any direction either from top to bottom as 5 4 3 2 1 (as in figure)

Or from bottom to top  5 4 3 2 1 .
Then I guess this hasse diagram has no maximal element and no minimal element ..am I correct?

As there is no maximal element there is no maximum element and similarly there is no minimum element ... Am I correct . ??? Please help

Comment: I don't understand what u said . U mean if I take the direction up then 5 is the maximal element and 1 is the minimal element . Also 5 is the maximum element and 1 is the minimal element . Am I correct??

Comment: An arrow is a direction -- it's either from low to high, or from high to low, but not both. The choice is arbitrary, but if the arrows go up, then that's low to high, and if the arrows are drawn downwards, then that's high to low. So for a given Hasse diagram, the directions are fixed.

Comment: So what is the answer in this case?

Comment: For the given Hasse diagram, 5 is maximum (hence also maximal), and 1 is minimum (hence also minimal).

Comment: Thanks. .......